# which path we have to set in build.gradle file to run python code in android

Tags: python, android

HI i am trying to execute python code using android kotlin code i have setup every thing i am facing only one issue that i am unable to give python executeable file path from mac machine .

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.chaquo.python'
}

    android {
        namespace 'com.alphacorp.instaloader'
        compileSdk 33
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.alphacorp.instaloader"
            minSdk 21
            targetSdk 33
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.4.1"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86_64"
            }
            python {
                version "3.8"
                buildPython "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pip3"
                pip {
                    // A requirement specifier, with or without a version number:
                    install "instaloader"
                }
            }
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
        sourceSets {
            main {
                python.srcDir "src/main/python"
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0"
    }
```

This is my build gradle but when i trying to build code i am getting error that
Process 'command '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pip3'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

please help me how to fix this issue  below is file i have set executable python file path

[image]

Comment: @azeem-idrisi could you please help me in this